# How to render a svg file to canvas within a webpack build environment?

Tags: canvas, svg, webpack

I want to render an svg file to canvas. I have a webpack setup so I imagine I can embed the svg within the webpack build. What is the best way to go about this?

I would like to use javascript to render the svg in the canvas.

Comment: I have only plugin answer so I post comment: *svg-inline-loader* https://github.com/sairion/svg-inline-loader will be solution for you. But this plugin is no more in maintenance - I couldn't find newer one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `file-loader` to copy the svg image to the output folder.

```
var can = document.getElementById('canvas1');
var ctx = can.getContext('2d');

var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
   ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
}
img.src = require('file!./example.svg');
```

if your webpack config is something like this,

```
...
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    ...
},
...
```

then your svg file would be copied to the dist folder.

Comment: Thx, I know about this, but want to embed the file, not load it after.

Comment: Then try using `svg-url` instead `file`